# pandas: multiply column depending on other column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with column a and b. I want to multiply column a with value x if b is true and with value y if b is false. What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do it in 2 steps:

```
df.loc[df.b, 'a'] *= x
df.loc[df.b == False, 'a'] *= y
```

Or in 1 step using `where`:

```
In [366]:

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':randn(5), 'b':[True, True, False, True, False]})
df
Out[366]:
          a      b
0  0.619641   True
1 -2.080053   True
2  0.379665  False
3  0.134897   True
4  1.580838  False

In [367]:

df.a *= np.where(df.b, 5,10)
df
Out[367]:
           a      b
0   3.098204   True
1 -10.400266   True
2   3.796653  False
3   0.674486   True
4  15.808377  False
```

Comment: This gives me a warning: C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numexpr\necompiler.py:746: DeprecationWarning: usi
ng `oa_ndim == 0` when `op_axes` is NULL is deprecated. Use `oa_ndim == -1` or t
he MultiNew iterator for NumPy <1.8 compatibility
  return compiled_ex(*arguments, **kwargs)
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py:389: SettingWithCopyWarnin
g: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_index,col_indexer] = value instead
  self.obj[item] = s

Comment: How about the first answer, I think my second answer uses chain indexing which is why you get the warning so I will remove that one

Comment: The warning comes with the first answer

Comment: how about `df.loc[df.b == True, 'a'] *= 5
df.loc[df.b == False, 'a'] *= 10`?

Comment: @beginner_ OK I fixed it up, it should be OK both versions now

Comment: @beginner_ what version of pandas, numpy and python are you using? I', using pandas 0.14.1, numpy 1.8.1 and python 64-bit 3.3.4

Comment: 32-bit on Windows, library versions are same as yours.

Comment: @beginner_ dunno works fine without any warnings on my environment, You could try [winpython](http://sourceforge.net/projects/winpython/files/WinPython_3.3/3.3.5.0/WinPython-64bit-3.3.5.0.exe/download) you'd need tp update pandas though from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pandas) it's very simple just open the winpython control panel and drop the exe into it to upgrade

Comment: OK. So it's a plaform issue. The linked version is actually the one I use. Anyway, the result is correct. For my use case I can live with the warning.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58941/discussion-between-edchum-and-beginner).

Comment: @beginner_ ignore chat request, what version numexpr are you using mine is `2.2.2`.

Comment: Was just checking that. it was 2.1. Updated to 2.4 and now the first warning is gone. The warning from pandas is still there.

Comment: @beginner_ presumably if you took a reference to column a this would remove the warning: `a = df.a  df.a = a * np.where(df.b == True, 5,10)`? Otherwise it could be a platform issue

Comment: Still gives warning. So platform issue

Comment: The `==True` seems unnecessary.